# SQLite database convert string back into blob

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a three SQLite databases, that need to be joined together. I have already tried following procedure:

(1) `SELECT column1, column2, quote(column3) from table1 - quote(X) is to convert blob field into string field`

(2)`I import table1.csv back into database, where i define first two fields as INTEGERin third as STRING`

(3) `I use: INSERT INTO table_new (column1, column2, column3) SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table1`

but it doesn't convert correctly (output is a picture.png)

There should be an function that is opposite to QUOTE and would return me back my converted data?

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in SQL function that converts a blob literal (`x'102234'`) back into a blob, because such a literal is intended to be used in SQL commands.

The easiest way to move data between databases is to use the [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) command-line tool:

```
sqlite3 old.db ".dump" > data.sql
sqlite3 new.db < data.sql
```

Other tools like SQLite Manager have similar functions to export/import databases.

Comment: hello, I have tried: sqlite3 osm_grayscale_slo.mbtiles ".dump" > data.sql and also osm_grayscale_slo.mbtiles ".dump" > sqlite_master.sql, but it didn't work :( what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am using SQLite Manager from Firefox and can't get the '.dump' function to work.

Comment: When I wrote "the sqlite3 command-line tool", I meant "the sqlite3 command-line tool" and not "SQLite Manager".

Comment: hello, I have figured this out, how to work with sqlite3 command tool. I think my main problem is that I have a database that has *.mbtiles ending and it doesn't recognise it. I think this would work on *db databases.

Comment: The actual file name does not matter.

Comment: how large databases can be managed with sqlite3 command line? my first database that has 400 mb was attached properly, but second one that is over 1,5 gb doesn't seem to be attached properly :( command .tables displays only tables from first table. is there another tool that manages larger databases?

Comment: Works for me. You should ask a new question for that.